# Redux doesn't call another function with dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an issue with calling function after calling dispatch in redux-thunk. It calls the regular functions like 'console.log' but ignores the declared function above. I got stuck with it and have no ideas how this could be solved.

**Actions**

````
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
    if(localStorage.token) {
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token)
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/auth')

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        })
    } catch(err) {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_ERROR
        })
    }
}


export const login = (formData) => async(dispatch) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/auth', formData, config)

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })

        loadUser() // THIS FUNCTION IS IGNORED
        console.log('test') // but this one is called.
    } catch(err) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload: err.response.data.msg
        })
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadUser()` returns a thunk, so you need to dispatch it:

```
dispatch(loadUser());
```

Comment: @KirillKosheev awesome! I've spent my fair share of time wrestling with Redux